# Bottom navigation not showing

Tags: android, xml, material-design

I am trying to implement bottom navigation menu. After multiple tries, I could not figure out what am I doing wrong.

I added in gradle:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

I updated activity main theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
```

I created the menu resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/item1"
    android:title="Item 1"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_black_24dp"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/item2"
    android:title="Item 2"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_black_24dp"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/item3"
    android:title="Item 3"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_black_24dp" />
</menu>
```

I added bottom navigation widget in main activity:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
```

The result:
[image: The result]

Has anyone encountered this?

Comment: Can I see your full code of layout file (BottomNavigationView)?

Comment: Yes, @mustafiz012
[activity_main.xml](https://ibb.co/3Y4kKdF) 
[bottom_navigation](https://ibb.co/pz065dS)

Comment: I've just used your layout, it's working fine. If you want, I can share a working basic example.

Comment: Yes, it would be great !

Comment: Please check this https://github.com/mustafiz012/BasicBottomNavigation out and let me know if you face any trouble.

Comment: I found the problem. itemColorTint and itemTextColor had the same color as the background of the navigation. It was white on white.

Comment: So you got the solution! 